# Cannot delete or update a parent row, a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, sql, database

When doing this DELETE code:

```
$update = "DELETE from  `products`  WHERE `product_code` = $id; ";
$updateResult = mysqli_query($link, $update) OR DIE("Update Query Error ".mysqli_error($link)."Query [".$update ."]");
```

It says an ERROR:

Update Query Error Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gibson_db`.`trans`, CONSTRAINT `prod_trans_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`product_code`) REFERENCES `products` (`product_code`))Query [DELETE from `products` WHERE `product_code` = 1; ]

Here are my related TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_code` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT 'N/A',
  `price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_type` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `img_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'products/',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_code`),
  KEY `prod_type_fk` (`product_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=37 ;

INSERT INTO `products` (`product_code`, `product_name`, `description`, `price`, `quantity`, `product_type`, `img_path`)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `producttype` (
  `product_type` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `producttype` (`product_type`, `description`)

ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `prod_type_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`product_type`) REFERENCES `producttype` (`product_type`);
```

Comment: What is `prod_trans_fk`?

Comment: It is the constraint name on my another table named `trans`.`ALTER TABLE `trans`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `prod_trans_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`product_code`) REFERENCES `products` (`product_code`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_trans_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_code`) REFERENCES `user_tbl` (`user_code`);`

Comment: Check my answer , it will solve your problem

Comment: @sumit, ok sir. i'll try. Thank you!

Comment: That's why it got error, because the child record at `trans` table becomes orphaned when you delete `products`. You can use @sumit's answer to resolve your problem.

Comment: I'am using xampp (phpmyadmin), do i need to use `cascade` instead of `restrict` on delete and on update?

Comment: cascade can be dangerous in your case as it will delete all transactions

Answer (score 3):

Your Product table has relationship with some other table may be **trans** with constraint `prod_trans_fk`. **Normally innodb will throw the error when you try to delete the parent record to avoid the orphan data**. Following are some alternatives

1. Delete the child  record 1st
2. Use cascading to delete all child records when parent is deleted.(can be dangerous eg: you might lose all transactions when you delete product)
3. **Use soft deletion(set flag like is_deleted to Yes or No)(highly recommended)**

Comment: good break down of typical ways of fixing only note would be it is ONE of the following not all of them